# Aligning menu items and sub menus in Semantic UI React

Tags: css, reactjs, vertical-alignment, semantic-ui, semantic-ui-react

I'm trying to figure out how to get a sub menu to align correctly with menu items in a Semantic UI react menu component.

Currently my component looks like this.

```
import React from "react";
import { Menu, Container, Dropdown } from "semantic-ui-react";

const menuStyle = {
  border: "none",
  borderRadius: 0,
  boxShadow: "none",
};

export const HeaderMenu = () => {
  return (
    <Menu pointing secondary borderless style={menuStyle} widths={5}>
      <Menu.Item>Home</Menu.Item>
      <Menu.Item link as="a" href="/about">
        About Me
      </Menu.Item>
      <Menu.Item link as="a" href="/contact">
        Contact
      </Menu.Item>
      <Menu.Item as="Menu">
        <Dropdown text="Projects" pointing className="link item">
          <Dropdown.Menu>
            <Dropdown.Item link as="a" href="/projects">
              All Projects
            </Dropdown.Item>
            <Dropdown.Divider />
            <Dropdown.Item>Computer Science</Dropdown.Item>
            <Dropdown.Item>Other projects</Dropdown.Item>
          </Dropdown.Menu>
        </Dropdown>
      </Menu.Item>

      <Menu.Item as="a"> Blog </Menu.Item>
    </Menu>
  );
};
```

When I render the component it looks like the sub menu is out of line with the rest of the menu items. The actual size is fine but I would like to vertically align them all to the middle. However adding the `verticalAlign: middle` style doesn't seem to be doing anything.

Output (with margin highlighting) :

[image: Sample menu image with margin highlighting]

Answer (score 0):

I managed to solve this by forcing the sub menu to include a `padding: "0"` value. I'm not sure if this is the best solution since it had to include custom css.